# How do you use AVAudioPlayer to play music while in the background?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, background, avaudioplayer, audiosession

I currently use AVAudioPlayer to play music while in the foreground, but when I press the home button my application goes to the background and the music stops.  I set the category for my AVAudioSession to AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback and set active to YES.  Additionally, I added the `audio` key to UIBackgroundModes in my Info.plist.

Is there anything else I need to do to enable background music playback?

Answer (score 2):

There's apparently a bug in the simulator - it doesn't work there, while it works fine on the device.

(Edit: and by "doesn't work" I mean the sound stops when the app enters background, yet the player's status remains "playing" and it seems to keep "playing", although you can't hear it).

Comment: This was the answer: simulator bug. Device works fine. Thx a mil