# run music in background running application in xcode

Tags: iphone

Kindly send me a code sample of how to run the music file when the application goes in the background. [iphone 4.1].

I don't want the music to stop when my application goes in the background just like the itunes music.

Best Regards,
Naveed Butt

Comment: 'This is what I want, create it for me.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add "audio" to UIBackgroundModes in your PLIST.

For playback to continue when the phone locks;

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>

AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];

NSError *setCategoryError = nil;
[audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:&setCategoryError];
if (setCategoryError) { /* handle the error condition */ }

NSError *activationError = nil;
[audioSession setActive:YES error:&activationError];
if (activationError) { /* handle the error condition */ }
```

Comment: Do not test on simulator, this works fine on the device. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3421128/how-do-you-use-avaudioplayer-to-play-music-while-in-the-background?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

You can see the sample in the book of Erica Sadun - how to play audio file ...