# Running MPMoviePlayer when the App goes into background

Tags: ios, ios6, mpmovieplayercontroller, mpmovieplayer

I am making an App  where i m running am streaming a radio url. But when the App goes into background it stops running. I want to run it when when the App enter background.
Can anyone help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simple. You need to register as a background audio app by including the UIBackgroundModes key (with the value audio) in its Info.plist file.

Note: Apps that include this key must play audible content to the user while in the background.

### Edit

For Xcode 4.6, go to plist-> Required Background Modes-> App Plays Audio

Comment: I am using iOS6 so i am not able to find UIBackgroundModes. Is it present there in iOS6?

Comment: Thanks. But how to enable UIBackgroundModes after adding it to .plist.So that when the app goes enters background, MPMoviePlayer stills plays radio stream??

Comment: If you set same on .plist then it will be enabled automatically.

Comment: check in viewWillDisappear or viewDidAppear, are you releasing something or stopping player?

Comment: Nope. Nothing am doing there.

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4005946/run-music-in-background-running-application-in-xcode

Comment: For that i need 15 reputations.

Comment: No, you dont need any reputation, just check on right tick mark. Also, with this your too will get reputation..

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by P.J., your app should register for background audio play.

**According to the [Apple Doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW28)**

- When the `UIBackgroundModes` key contains the audio value, the system’s
  media frameworks automatically prevent the corresponding app from
  being suspended when it moves to the background. As long as it is
  playing audio or video content, the app continues to run in the
  background. However, if the app stops playing the audio or video, the
  system suspends it.